# How to control multiple device with one device offline(Over WIFI only)

Tags: java, android, remote-access

I won't make a controller control multiple devices over WIFI(no internet connection).

I check [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en) is working like that, I make an app like that which control devices which all have the same app. How I control these without FCM or mediator(server) in between this

I tried something like AirDroid work

I add the device with this code same network connect device

```
 final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setView(new EditText(this));
    alertDialog.show();
    Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();
    window.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_new);
    final EditText editName = (EditText)window.findViewById(R.id.editName);
    final EditText editAddress = (EditText)window.findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
    Button btnSave = (Button)window.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    Button btnCancel = (Button)window.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int primaryKey = database.getPrimaryKeyNum()+1;
            Device device = new Device(primaryKey,editName.getText().toString(),R.drawable.ad_ic_device_default,editAddress.getText().toString(),2027);
            database.createTable(device);
            database.insert(device);
            deviceList.add(device);
            deviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listDevices.setSelection(deviceList.size());
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Add succeed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

[you can check full example here](https://github.com/Pacey6/AirDroid)

[Also using Wifi P2p Connection](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo)

Comment: So have you code something ?

Comment: Yes I try something I add code,  please give me some time